# Best way to handle authentication on a react-redux single page appliction?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, single-page-application

I'm currently sending the client an empty html document with a few scripts included that set up my single page application with react-redux. After everything is set up I'm fetching the dynamic data using AJAX and determine if the user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in, he will see the products available only for users that are not authenticated and conversely.

Even though I am a noob, this seems extremly primitive to me and I don't know how I can do this better.

So what is the best way to handle authentication in react-redux applications?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: If you're looking for articles and tutorials and such then don't post here, just go and google for them. There's plenty of resources regarding react/redux authentication out there. If you're expecting someone here on SO to post a giant answer covering the topic in great detail then sorry to say but that's not the point of SO. Google it, check out some resources, try to implement them in your own project and if you have specific issues with some part of your code then you can post that here and get help for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few options:

1. Passport which you can install through npm and it has a variety of strategies you can authenticate through such as Auth0 [Link here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)
2. Firebase - a solution that google has that can be used as a drop-in authentication module. [Link here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)
3. Meteor framework - I believe this framework has multi user authentication. [Link here](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html)

Answer (score 0):

First,  for authentification you need to have a token or session id on the client side. So, there should be next steps:

1. After login, you receive token|session_id from backend and put it to the store and also to the localstorage not to lose it after page reload.
2. While initializing your app, get the token from localstorage and put it to the store every time.
3. When you do request for products list, add the token to ajax request (usually in headers).
4. Based on token, back-end application should returns another list of products.

It is a regular logic for such situations and of course it requires work on back-end side as well.